# Access exported component within the component

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to send the component from within the component meaning when I have this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my.template.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
    private myVar: any;

    constructor(){

    }
    myFunction() =>{

    }
}
```

Outside of the class I can simply call:

```
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
```

But I would like to get `MyComponent` within the class:

```
 myFunction() =>{
     this.myVar = **MyComponment**
 }
```

How to get `**MyComponent**`?

Please note that I don't want the instance but need the class itself.

**EDIT:**
I realize my question is not clear enough. Here is what I need to do... I need to extract the component and recreate it somewhere else. In another component I have the following:

```
export class MyOtherComponent {    
    constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){

    }
    createComponent(myComponent) =>{
        var factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(myComponent);
        var compRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(factory);
        container.getElement().append($(compRef.location.nativeElement));
    }
}
```

So Inside `MyComponent` I want to be able to do this:

```
myFunction() =>{
    this.myOtherComponent.createComponent(**MyComponent**)
}
```

Comment: You can refer to component class as `MyComponent` or `this.constructor`. What purpose should `this.myVar = **MyComponment**` serve? It doesn't smell too good.

Comment: @estus I know it's not super clean but I need to extract the component and recreate it somewhere else. One option would be to list all the component wherever I want to recreate them but I would prefer to avoid and make it more flexible by sending it as an argument...does it make sense?

Comment: @estus BTW I recreate the component as follow `this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);` so `this.constructor` gives me the following error: `No component factory found for MyComponent` Any idea what I could do?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood this correctly, but getting a constructor from component instance and sending it elsewhere doesn't look like a fine pattern to me. Specifying the details on supposed usage in the question would help to get a quality answer, I guess. `MyComponent` doesn't have `Component` decorator, so technically, it is not a component.

Comment: @estus Please see my edit and let me know if it is still not clear enough...sorry about that

Comment: And how `createComponent` is used? What prevents you from importing a desired component class and doing `createComponent(MyComponent)`?

Comment: @estus Nothing but I need to do that for 30 Components so I don't want to have a long list in `MyOtherComponent`. In addition I want to make it flexible so whenever I add a new Component I don't need to add it to `MyOtherComponent`

Comment: Where exactly is `createComponent` called? It isn't clear why you need to do what you're trying to do in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127009/discussion-between-ncohen-and-estus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just refer to it with the class name.

```js
class MyComponent {
    private myVar: MyComponent;

    constructor(){
        console.log("created!")
    }
    myFunction () {
        var myVar = MyComponent;
        new myVar();
    }
}
```

You can check out the resulting js [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyComponent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20myVar%3A%20MyComponent%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(%22created!%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myFunction%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09var%20myVar%20%3D%20MyComponent%3B%0D%0A%09%09new%20myVar()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20MyComponent().myFunction()%3B).

Comment: Thanks please see my edit for more details... basically with your solution I'm getting the following error: `No component factory found for MyComponent` whenever I call `resolveComponentFactory()`

Comment: I forgot to add `MyComponent` into `entryComponents` in my modules